# Use VBoxManage from code or libvirt?

Tags: java, virtualbox, libvirt

I am currently doing a project that needs VirtualBox as third party software. It doesn't need to do very complex stuff, basicly just import an .ova, forward a port, start it, export it again and some cleanup (never more than 1 vm at the time).

This will all be written in Java and needs to work in both linux and windows. My question is, what do you guys think is a better approach? Right now I'm just using the VBoxManage application (which is also exactly the same on both platforms), which means that I can use exactly the same code without any libraries in windows and linux, the only thing that's different is the binary path.

On the other hand, if something in the VBoxManage syntax changes that means it has to be updated and libvirt probably fixes this for you in an easier way.

Point is, I'm not sure what to do, libvirt seems awfully complex and big for something as simple as this and the library itself is also not platform independent =\. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will stick with VboxManage. Even when the command syntax changes, it is simpler to manage.

Using libvirt may mean using JNI and more code and more maintenance.